# Animated featurette about a boy who befriends old junky, clumsy robot in a Jetsons-like future setting

Tags: story-identification, robots, animation

First off I don't think this was a full length movie, nor do I think it was connected to a series. I think it might have been some sort of featurette. I found this VHS in a library when I was a child and I borrowed it over and over again in the mid '90s but it might be older. First I'll list what I'm certain of, then the scenes that I think happened, just to try and keep it clear.

So in a sort of Jetsons-future, a boy finds an old junky robot and befriends him. He takes him home and his parents let him (reluctantly?) keep it and he is left to do chores around the house with the boy.

The robot is fully humanoid, with a wide upper chest giving him a bit of a buff look. He is orange, tall (at least as tall as the parents), with his hands and forearms being grey. He has a face (with, I think, a light bulb nose and a wide brim on his head making it seem like he is wearing a park ranger style hat), he has boot like feet. I believe the boy and his two parents had dark skin but they definitely had black hair and the father had a decently thick mustache.

There is a state of the art model Butler robot that had a very distinct appearance; it was all metallic grey with visible paneling, a round head that I think had a powered wig design and a human shaped torso with thick arms that ended in hands with white dusting gloves. The Butler robot wore a sleeveless tuxedo top with a bow tie and long coat tails that almost go to the ground. Rather than legs, from the chest down the robot had a body that looked like a stretched out hourglass shape that made him at lest as tall as the Old Junky robot that ended on a flat square metal piece that then had four small wheels on it's sides near the corners which it roll round with to move. This is what it had in lieu of legs/feet.

**Scenes I remember with certainty:**

The robot is charged with cleaning the home and with the boy in tow goes to a separate room (parents are not in this scene) to the vacuum cleaner. He takes off the nozzle off the vacuum (the nozzle has the standard cartoon shape reminiscent of the upholstery tool nozzle) and places it over his forearm (while talking to the boy) causing him to gain a vacuum hand. The nozzle completely covers his forearm and works.

Parents come home to find the Robot has made them a meal, the future stove is shown and it has a large tall metallic cylinder with a dome top siting on the stove top with a metal bar on the top of the dome (seems to be a heat cover that is lowered from about along the bar in a piston motion). Comments are made on the meal (homemade chili) and it's high quality. The tall cylinder is raised via the piston-like bar attached to the top (activated remotely by either a parent or the robot) to reveal a huge and tall pot filled with chili, causing the father to exclaim "He made enough to feed an army" in dismay, while the boy is pleased with this and says "I love it" (referring to the chili). The boy was present for the meals perpetration but it is not shown being made.

After the Old robot is gone (I am not 100% sure of the exact reason he is gone) the parents get the state of the art butler robot, and that morning the parents (specifically the father) are served breakfast by the new butler bot, the father complain about the meal on plate with is a white substance called "Insta-mush". when asking what it was the butler bot states "it is a nutritious insta-mush from a special recipe" the father declines the meal and says he'll just have a cup of coffee to which the butler bot replies "nonsense I shall prepare you a nutritious insta-drink" to which the father responses "but I want coffee!"

**Scenes I think I remember:**

At first the boy wants the state of the art butler robot but his parents say no (too expensive?), he stumbles across the old junky robot in the trash. The robot is not deactivated and is aware that he was thrown out. He may have even just been siting on a pile of trash.

There is a white boy the main boy knows who is a bit of a show off jerk/bully, who already has the state of the art butler robot. Soon after the main boy befriends the Junky bot the bully challenges him and his junk bot (against him and his butler robot) to some sort of future ball scoring game (might be in zero G). The butler robot grabs the ball from a great distance at one point by using one hand to press a button on the inside base of the other causing that arm to extend (not unlike Bender's extendo arms).

The Old junky robot overhears the parents either complaining about him or talking about getting rid of him and sadly leaves on his own OR his unintentional hijinks put the boy in some sort of danger and this prompts the robot to leave. Either or I think the Old robot leaves of his own accord.

**The Plot Summary (or as near as I can remember it)**

Story is about a boy who wants a robot (other than helping around the house they are seen playing around with kids as well) and finds a old junky robot, he brings it home and is told he can keep him but hijinks ensue and the Robot leaves. The boy is sad and angry over losing his friend and his parents try and cheer him up by getting the state of the art butler robot the boy originally wanted. His doesn't work and the boy goes to find his the old robot and parents realize they don't like the new butler robot. It ends with the Old robot ending up back with the boy and the parents but I don't remember how, he MIGHT have saved the boy from some kind of crusher or smelter in the garbage disposal room where the boy went to find the Old robot

One thing last thing, I remember it having better animation (quite good, in fact) than something like the Jetsons (but just a similar future setting) but that could just be because things always seem better when your a kid and on that note this could have even been a for kids Anime OVA VHS that simply didn't look overtly anime but I don't think it was (but you never know, best to keep an open mind)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hadn't known that this had been animated until I did a search, but you're looking for "[C.L.U.T.Z.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1254408/)", an animated segment on Season 2, Episode 1, of *[CBS Storybreak](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0272370/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)*, and an adaptation of the
[Marilyn Z. Wilkes book of the same name](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4312358-c-l-u-t-z), which was a story-id question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/185560/23243). Summary from Goodreads of the book:

> Eleven-year-old Rodney makes a new friend when a broken-down robot with an almost human personality comes to work for his family.

### Part 1 of the episode

### Part 2

I'm familiar with the book because we had it in our house when I was a child, and I read it many times.

Comment: oh my god you are amazing! I've been looking for this forever, thank you so much. I'm quite frankly surprised how much I got right consider my age at the time and how long it had been.